# Setting custom loss causes RuntimeError: Variable data has to be a tensor, but got Variable in Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, runtime-error, pytorch

I have custom class for the net definition:

```
class PyTorchUNet(Model):
    ....
    def set_loss(self):
            if self.activation_func == 'softmax': #this is working example
                 loss_function = partial(mixed_dice_cross_entropy_loss,
                                dice_loss=multiclass_dice_loss,
                                cross_entropy_loss=nn.CrossEntropyLoss(),
                                dice_activation='softmax',
                                dice_weight=self.architecture_config['model_params']['dice_weight'],
                                cross_entropy_weight=self.architecture_config['model_params']['bce_weight']
                                )

            elif self.activation_func == 'sigmoid':
                    loss_function = designed_loss #setting will cause error on validation

            else:
                raise Exception('Only softmax and sigmoid activations are allowed')
            self.loss_function = [('mask', loss_function, 1.0)]

    def designed_loss(output, target):
       target = target.long() # this should make variable to tensor
       return lovasz_hinge(output, target)

    # this is just as it from github
    def lovasz_hinge(logits, labels, per_image=True, ignore=None):
        """
        Binary Lovasz hinge loss
          logits: [B, H, W] Variable, logits at each pixel (between -\infty and +\infty)
          labels: [B, H, W] Tensor, binary ground truth masks (0 or 1)
          per_image: compute the loss per image instead of per batch
          ignore: void class id
        """
        if per_image:
            loss = mean(lovasz_hinge_flat(*flatten_binary_scores(log.unsqueeze(0), lab.unsqueeze(0), ignore))
                              for log, lab in zip(logits, labels))
        else:
            loss = lovasz_hinge_flat(*flatten_binary_scores(logits, labels, ignore))
        return loss


    def lovasz_hinge_flat(logits, labels):
        """
        Binary Lovasz hinge loss
          logits: [P] Variable, logits at each prediction (between -\infty and +\infty)
          labels: [P] Tensor, binary ground truth labels (0 or 1)
          ignore: label to ignore
        """
        if len(labels) == 0:
            # only void pixels, the gradients should be 0
            return logits.sum() * 0.
        signs = 2. * labels.float() - 1.
        errors = (1. - logits * Variable(signs))
        errors_sorted, perm = torch.sort(errors, dim=0, descending=True)
        perm = perm.data
        gt_sorted = labels[perm]
        grad = lovasz_grad(gt_sorted)
        loss = torch.dot(F.elu(errors_sorted), Variable(grad))
        return loss
    def mean(l, ignore_nan=False, empty=0):
        """
        nanmean compatible with generators.
        """
        l = iter(l)
        if ignore_nan:
            l = ifilterfalse(np.isnan, l)
        try:
            n = 1
            acc = next(l)
        except StopIteration:
            if empty == 'raise':
                raise ValueError('Empty mean')
            return empty
        for n, v in enumerate(l, 2):
            acc += v
        if n == 1:
            return acc
        return acc / n
```

**Working example:**

```
def mixed_dice_cross_entropy_loss(output, target, dice_weight=0.5, dice_loss=None,
                                  cross_entropy_weight=0.5, cross_entropy_loss=None, smooth=0,
                                  dice_activation='softmax'):
    num_classes_without_background = output.size(1) - 1
    dice_output = output[:, 1:, :, :]
    dice_target = target[:, :num_classes_without_background, :, :].long()
    cross_entropy_target = torch.zeros_like(target[:, 0, :, :]).long()
    for class_nr in range(num_classes_without_background):
        cross_entropy_target = where(target[:, class_nr, :, :], class_nr + 1, cross_entropy_target)
    if cross_entropy_loss is None:
        cross_entropy_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    if dice_loss is None:
        dice_loss = multiclass_dice_loss
    return dice_weight * dice_loss(dice_output, dice_target, smooth,
                                   dice_activation) + cross_entropy_weight * cross_entropy_loss(output,
                                                                                                cross_entropy_target)

def multiclass_dice_loss(output, target, smooth=0, activation='softmax'):
    """Calculate Dice Loss for multiple class output.

    Args:
        output (torch.Tensor): Model output of shape (N x C x H x W).
        target (torch.Tensor): Target of shape (N x H x W).
        smooth (float, optional): Smoothing factor. Defaults to 0.
        activation (string, optional): Name of the activation function, softmax or sigmoid. Defaults to 'softmax'.

    Returns:
        torch.Tensor: Loss value.

    """
    if activation == 'softmax':
        activation_nn = torch.nn.Softmax2d()
    elif activation == 'sigmoid':
        activation_nn = torch.nn.Sigmoid()
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError('only sigmoid and softmax are implemented')

    loss = 0
    dice = DiceLoss(smooth=smooth)
    output = activation_nn(output)
    num_classes = output.size(1)
    target.data = target.data.float()
    for class_nr in range(num_classes):
        loss += dice(output[:, class_nr, :, :], target[:, class_nr, :, :])
    return loss / num_classes
```

As result I keep getting:

```
RuntimeError: Variable data has to be a tensor, but got Variable
```

**How to fix the problem?**

Comment: Asking for clarification: Is the "causes error on validation" with respect to every call of the loss function, or just for the *validation data*? Have you tried explicitly setting `requires_grad=False` for the targets, before/after casting them?

Comment: Yes, for every call, I face it at the end of the batch, will try

Comment: If it is only for the validation data, you should look into the differences between how you pass training and validation data to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you still use pytorch 0.3?

if yes, the following snippet may help

`tensor = var.data`